# React Native get pressed key of exernal Keyboard

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

I currently try to connect an external keyboard (Barcode-Scanner) to my React-Native App.

If i add an hidden TextInput, and set the focus on the TextInput in componentDidMount the keyboard is shown.

Is there a possibility to get the pressed key on the external Keyboard, or hide the Keyboard in the TextInput? Need this for Android and iOS.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Now we can do this like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639041/react-native-textinput-with-focus-but-without-keyboard-showing